# FBX export causes animation problems

Tags: animation, export, .fbx

I have created a model with some animations that I'd like to export to FBX in order to use in Unity. However, when I export the file and play back the animations in Unity, they are messed up and glitchy. I have confirmed this is not a Unity error, as the animations are messed up (in exactly the same way) when importing the FBX file back into Blender. I have tried disabling NLA strips and All Actions and toggling every other relevant export setting separately, but nothing seems to work.

Here's the blend file: https://pasteall.org/blend/5ee27dfea5724bd2b750fa21bd54a336

Using Blender 2.83.4 Windows 64.

Thanks a bunch for any help.